# How to specify Destination for Core Data fetchRequest programmatically?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Im trying to perform a fetch request programmatically to retrieve certain entities from "EntityA". However i need to  set the Destination for the fetch request to "EntityB" for the predicate to work similar to how you would do so through the inspector panel in XC? Cant figure out how to set this property programmatically though?

Thx

Comment: did you try to set the entity of the nsfetchrequest.

Comment: i might be confused but i am setting the entity to EntityA which is the type of entity i want returned, however i need to set the destination to a diff entity, EntityB, because that is how my predicate is structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each fetch only has one entity as it's target. The predicate for a fetch can only operate on the attributes and relationships of the target entity. If you want to test a property of another entity, there must be a relationship from the target entity to the other entity.

Suppose you have the following data model:

```
Alpha{
  name:string
  beta<-->Beta.alpha
}

Beta{
  cost:number
  alpha<-->Alpha.beta
}

Gamma{
  date:date
}
```

If your target entity for the fetch is `Alpha` then you can create a predicate that test an attribute of `Beta` through each `Alpha` object's `beta` relationship.

```
NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"beta.number>5"];
```

... but you can't create a predicate that will access an attribute of `Gamma` because there is no relationship.

Comment: follow-up question though. What is the "Destination" field used for in the inspector panel when creating a Fetched Property?? It is possible to set this to a diff value than the entity that the Fetched Property belongs to?

Comment: any thoughts on above comment?